# Improve Performance with a Pause on an Infinite Gradient Animation

Tags: css, background, transition, gradient, pause

For performance reasons, I would like to add a pause to an infinite gradient animation, which was created using https://www.gradient-animator.com/, to give web browsers a break from rendering transitions between different colors.

Here's an example script created using the aforementioned website.

```
.css-selector {
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #3adab1, #3a7bda, #853ada);
    background-size: 600% 600%;

    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on achieving this by modifing this CSS? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This [site](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-play-and-pause-css-animations-with-css-custom-properties/) says it's achievable by cycling between the 'paused' and 'running' states, though I'm not sure how I'd implement it to this exactly. I've searched Google and Stackoverflow which led me to creating this.

Answer (score 0):

The animation can go from 0 to 50% of the animation duration then stay at the same place for the 50% to 100% duration.

So, this snippet puts the duration to 60s. On my laptop the gpu is used just under 50% for30 seconds, then 0% for30 seconds and so on.

The user does get to see the same static colors for half the time. I assune this is what is required by 'paused'.

```html
<style>
  .css-selector {
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #3adab1, #3a7bda, #853ada);
    background-size: 600% 600%;
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 60s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 60s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 60s ease infinite;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
      background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
  }
  
  @-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
      background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes AnimationName {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    25% {
      background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    50%,
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="css-selector"></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate it! Also, thanks for validating it with your GPU.